# Proof that a function is L-Lipschitz if its gradient norm is bounded by L

Tags: functional-analysis

A function f is said to be L-Lipschitz in a compact set $\mathcal{D}$  if

$||f(y)-f(x)|| \leq L ||y-x||, \quad \forall x,y \in \mathcal{D}$

I want to prove that if

$||\nabla f(x)|| \leq L , \quad \forall x \in \text{int}(\mathcal{D})$,

then the function f is L-Lipschitz.

The argument relies on the mean value theorem which states that $\exists c \in \text{int}(\mathcal{D})$ such that

$f(y)-f(x)=\nabla f(c)(y-x) \quad (1)$.

Since $ ||\nabla f(c)|| \leq L$, then by (1) $||f(y)-f(x)|| \leq L||y-x||$.

Is this proof correct? Regards.

Comment: The domain should be convex rather than compact. Also the form of the mean value theorem you stated is only true for functions of one real variable. In higher dimensions the replacement is an inequality

Comment: The proof is correct for scalar valued functions.